# simple section navigation plugin : which code in wordpress select the widgets to display when clicking on a page?

Tags: wordpress, widget

i use a widget called "simple section navigation " that display page sibling and ancestors at the sidebar for better navigation.

It worked in the past for previous created pages.
When i now create a new page , the widget does not show up anymore and display instead the default sidebar .

I am aware that this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-section-navigation/ has not been updated for 2years
I have noticed by wp_debug that the function _getancestors is deprecated and i have tried get_ancestors with no changes

i then tried to use the widget http://wordpress.org/plugins/hierarchical-navigation-widget/  and i have the same problem

i have checked with

```
    echo '<pre>';print_r(get_ancestors( 19, 'page' ))  ;
```

and validated that on page creation, the ancestors are correctly recorded and return the correct ancestors

Interesting it works with:

```
 simple_section_nav('before_widget=<li>&after_widget=</li>');
```

and does display the hierarchical page sibling and ancestors .
why is the widget not working then?

Any idea on where to find in the wordpress code where it select which sidebars to display  on each page? and in which case it returns the defaut sidebar?

Comment: Is [this the plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-section-navigation/)? With [this support thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-_get_post_ancestors-is-deprecated-error-with-wp-35?replies=3)? Please, add [debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) information to your Q.

Comment: this is it indeed , i have re-edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was not simple section navigation plugin widget but the sidebar from my theme that encapsulates the plugin widget.

For information for other users , the simple section navigation plugin does work with wordpress 3.5.2.
simply replace

```
 _get_ancestors function by 

 get_ancestors
```